# @Field() with Custom Class DTO file

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I'm tried to figure out what's the problem with my code.
I want to include class with my DTO file my he said to me
"Cannot Determine a graphQL inputType for the "myField". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.

the code looks like this:

```
@ObjectType()
export class GeoData {
    @Field((type) => String)
    type: string

    @Field(() => String)
    properties: string
    
}


@InputType()
export class LocatorCreateDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Field(() => String)
    name: string;
    
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Field(() => String)
    lastName: string
    
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ValidateNested({ each: true})
    @Type(() => GeoData)
    @Field((type) => GeoData)
    geoData: GeoData
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a name for the inputType ?
for example :

```
@InputType('LocatorCreateInput')
```